# How to add a class to a link using next() function in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a link inside a class which have active class. I want to find the next link of that active class and add active class in the new link. I tried to use `next()` function but it is not working.

```js
$("#next").on("click", function() {
  $(".test a.active").next(".test a").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx active">a</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">b</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">c</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">d</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">e</a></div>

<button id="next">click</button>
```

Comment: The `.test` classes are not siblings of the `<a>` elements. You'll need to traverse up the parent `<div>` before calling `next()` then traverse down to the `<a>` element within

Comment: @Phil I don't have much knowledge about Jquery can you  please give an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `.next` for `.test` instead of `a`

```js
$("#next").on("click", function() {
 const cls = $("a.active");   
 cls.removeClass('active') // remove previous active if you need
 cls.closest('.test').next(".test").children('a').addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx active">a</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">b</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">c</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">d</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">e</a></div>

<button id="next">click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get index of your `test` div where `a` tag has `active` class .Then ,using that index get next div and add active class to its children i.e : a tag.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#next").on("click", function() {
  var index_ = $("a.active").closest(".test").index() + 1 //get index of div ..which has active class add 1 
  $(".testx").removeClass("active") //remove from others 
  $(".test:eq(" + index_ + ") .testx").addClass("active"); //add to next
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--give some outer div-->
<div>
  <div class="test"><a href="" class="testx active">a</a></div>
  <div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">b</a></div>
  <div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">c</a></div>
  <div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">d</a></div>
  <div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">e</a></div>
</div>
<button id="next">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is not working because you added the selector inside the next() code which means it will select that element, not the next element and also the element "a" has no next element but rather the div.

Solution, upon trigger of next check the parent div next element then select the children which is "a" and add the class active. Please see code below.

```js
$("#next").on("click", function() {
  $(".test a.active").removeClass( "active" ).parent().next().children().addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx active">a</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">b</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">c</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">d</a></div>
<div class="test"><a href="" class="testx">e</a></div>

<button id="next">click</button>
```